# Match start of line or an arbitrary number of spaces

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I would like to convert

- `Hello a/b hi` into `Hello \frac{a}{b} hi`
- `a/b hi` into `\frac{a}{b} hi`
- `Hello a/b` into `Hello \frac{a}{b}`

where `a` and `b` is any non space character, using Lua patterns.

I came up with a pattern for each of those 3 cases:

```
line, _ = string.gsub(line, "%s+(%S+)/(%S+)%s+", "\\frac{%1}{%2}")
line, _ = string.gsub(line, "^(%S+)/(%S+)%s+", "\\frac{%1}{%2}")
line, _ = string.gsub(line, "%s+(%S+)/(%S+)$", "\\frac{%1}{%2}")
```

Is it possible to condense them into a single regular expression?

Because `[^%s]` would resolve to the complement of the `%s` character class, that is, all non-space characters (equivalent to `%S`), rather than space or start of line.

Comment: I don't know Lua but wouldn't `line, _ = string.gsub(line, "(%S+)/(%S+)", "\\frac{%1}{%2}")` work?

Comment: The fact that you are using whitespace boundaries makes it clear you do not even need to check for whitespaces before/after the match and for the start/end of string. Simply use `string.gsub(line, "(%S+)/(%S+)", "\\frac{%1}{%2}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One regular expression is:

```
function replaceFraction(str)
    str = string.gsub(str, "(%S+)/(%S+)", "\\frac{%1}{%2}")
    return str
end
```

Examples:

```
print(replaceFraction("Hello a/b hi")) -- Hello \frac{a}{b} hi
print(replaceFraction("a/b hi")) -- \frac{a}{b} hi
print(replaceFraction("Hello a/b")) -- Hello \frac{a}{b}
```